# How to generate a unique code in C#?

Tags: c#, random

In my asp.net solution (web part in sharepoint 2010), I insert JavaScript code using the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` code. But to insert it, I need to give a name for the script. The problem is that, if I insert a second solution in the same page, it will load the script again using the same name. And the way the registerstartup script works, is if there is an inserted script with the same name, then it wont insert the script.

So basically, I would like to create a function that would just give me a unique string every time I call the function. Basically there should never be a time, where the output of the function is the same as the output from the function at a different time. Then I can just attach this to the name, and then it will work for both solutions on the page.

Does anyone know how to create a random generating function in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use GUIDs?

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: If the hyphens are a problem, you can use `ToString("N")`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is [Path.GetRandomFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) just call that and it will give you a random string for your file, All you need to do is append your extension on it

```
var newFileName = Path.Combine(baseBath, Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".js");
```